# Form post to external url through an aura component embedded in community page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, community-builder, form, post

Is it possible to execute a form post to an external site from an aura component that is exposed in a community page?

Our aura component looks like this

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" onstatuschange="{!c.handleStatusChange}" />

    <form name="paymentForm" aura:id="paymentForm" action="https://..." method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="ccId" value="123" />
    </form>
</aura:component>
```

and we'd like to do something like this; set our form variables using the output variables from the flow before submit

```
handleStatusChange : function (component, event) {
    if(event.getParam("status") === "FINISHED") {
        var outputVariables = event.getParam("outputVariables");
        //set form variable using output variables from flow
        component.find("paymentForm").submit();
    }
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this through a form tag in Lightning Aura Components (do regular form tags even work there?), but you can just use regular inputs and other components to gather the data that you want to send. From there, you can package that data up and send it to a controller class to create an HttpRequest object, select the endpoint, and add the form data in the body. Then send it through an Http object.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm#apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the submit to this works:

```
component.find("paymentForm").getElement().submit();
```